# BMP Drain Inspection

Tags: drainage, landscaping

We have a new house, and we were going through our "stuff to do each year" list in the house manual.

We have what we colloquially refer to as a "box of rocks" that's part of the landscape draining system, it's a filter of some kind.

According to our book, we need to have this inspected, but also need to fill out some kind of form and that it's due on Sept. 15th.

Now, we did not do this last year, and never received any notice about it.

This seems to be related to something called "BMP", "Best Management Practices" regarding waste water. Everything I've seen seems to be either at the county or city level, but I'm not finding very much about residential responsibilities regarding this. It all seems very high level, or deep policy and compliance things.

But, I don't know what **I** need to do here for this. I can't seem to find any "form" either at the city or county level. It does not seem to be just a state (I'm in California) thing, but national standard.

I'm just wondering if anyone is familiar with this area and could give some general advice about what may need to be done and how to go about doing it.

Comment: BMP is meant for storm water. Waste water typically would be stuff that goes into your plumbing, from sinks, showers, and toilets. What is this book you refer to that says you need to get it inspected? I would contact whoever gave you, or published this book.

Comment: Contact your city or county water department - whoever you write your water bill check to. _Wait, do people actually write checks anymore?_